# ReplaceAll a list of rules to an equation

Tags: equation-solving, rule

Given the following equation and rule, how would I `Solve` the equation for `tr`, `k` and `c`?

```
eq = T == tr - E^(-k * t)*c;
rule = {t -> {0, 5, 10}, T -> {2000, 1300, 1100}};
```

`eq /. rule` results in this, which is almost what I want:

```
{2000, 1300, 1100} == {tr - c, tr - c/E^(5k), tr - c/E^(10k)}
```

I would like to get a list of equations instead like so:

```
{2000 == tr - c, 1300 == tr - c/E^(5k), 1100 == tr - c/E^(10k)}
```

which could then be used to solve the equations (using `And` on the list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinguin Dirk's solution is very neat for this problem. It is possible because, as you discovered, `eq /. rule` generates

```
{2000, 1300, 1100} == {tr - c, tr - c/E^(5*k), tr - c/E^(10*k)}
```

But this is often not the case! It works only because `Power` (`^`) has the attribute `Listable`. Let's say instead of `Power[E,t k]` we had `f[E,t k]` where `f` is any function that is not `Listable`. `eq /. rule` yields:

```
{2000, 1300, 1100} == tr - c f[E, {0, -5 k, -10 k}]
```

If you run into this problem, a more general approach would be needed. The key to the general approach is to get your rules into this format:

```
rules = Thread[Thread /@ {t -> {0, 5, 10}, T -> {2000, 1300, 1100}}]
```

> `{{t -> 0, T -> 2000}, {t -> 5, T -> 1300}, {t -> 10, T -> 1100}}`

Because in this format we can easily generate the required results, like this:

```
eq /. rules
```

> `{2000 == tr - c f[E, 0], 1300 == tr - c f[E, -5 k], 1100 == tr - c
>   f[E, -10 k]}`

Comment: The `# & /@` part is redundant as a list mapped to the identity function will return the same list. `eq /. rules` is enough.

Comment: @Tyilo Very observant of you, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Tyilo Although I would maintain it's not because of the reason you mention. `{expr /. {a->b}, expr /. {b->c}}` would not be the same as `expr /. {{a->b},{b->c}}` unless `ReplaceAll` had the seemingly undocumented property of threading over it's second argument.

Comment: oh I didn't know that what you wrote before is equal to `(eq /. #)& /@ rules)`. I thought it was `eq /. (# & /@ rules)` or something else, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Use for example:

```
Thread[eq/. rule]
```

and get:

> `{2000 == -c + tr, 1300 == -c E^(-5 k) + tr, 1100 == -c E^(-10 k) + tr}`

Comment: @Tyilo: Thanks for the accept, but usually it pays to wait a bit... there are most certainly other people out there with other ideas, better ideas. And you don't wanna scare them away, do you? Still, I am glad you like my approach!

Comment: Fair enough, I'll wait a little longer